MySQL stored procedure error with two cursors in the same routine "ER_SP_CURSOR_NOT_OPEN: Cursor is not open"
In this stored procedure for an inventory system I want to process a packaging order for a product in kg according to the type of container and its capacity in kg.
This finally stores the existence of the packaged product in the table "itemsenvasado".
I used two cursors because:

For the product which has more than one batch in stock
For the container which has more than one batch in stock

CREATE DEFINER=`soporte`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insertarItemEnvasado`(
    IN ordenID_in           INT,                -- ID de la Orden
    IN lote_orden_in        VARCHAR(45),        -- Lote de la Orden de Envasado
    IN bod_origenID_in      INT,                -- ID Bodega de Origen
    IN bod_destinoID_in     INT,                -- ID Bodega de Destino
    IN productoID_in        INT,                -- ID Producto a Envasar
    IN cantidad_kg_envasar  DECIMAL(10,2),      -- Cantidad KG a Envasar
    IN envaseID_in          INT,                -- ID Envase
    IN capacidad_envase     DECIMAL(10,2),      -- Capacidad de Envase
    IN cantidad_envase      DECIMAL(10,2),      -- Cantidad de Envases
    IN codigo_final_in      VARCHAR(45),        -- Codigo del Producto Envasado Final
    IN userID_in            INT                 -- ID Usuario que hizo la Transaccion
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE total_kg_envasar    DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE total_envases       INT;
    DECLARE kg_restante         DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE envases_restantes   INT;
    DECLARE precio_unitario     DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE precio_por_kg       DECIMAL(10,2);
    
    DECLARE lote_id INT;
    DECLARE lote_cantidad DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE lote_precio DECIMAL(10,2);
    
    DECLARE envase_lote_id INT;
    DECLARE envase_cantidad INT;
    DECLARE precio_envase INT;
    
    -- Cursor para Procesar los lotes de producto granel
    DECLARE cur_lotes_envasado CURSOR FOR
    SELECT id, precio, cantidadenvasar
    FROM controlstock.lotesenvasado
    WHERE ordenID = ordenID_in
    ORDER BY fecInsert;
    
    -- Cursor para Procesar los lotes de envases
    DECLARE cur_envases CURSOR FOR
    SELECT id, stock
    FROM controlstock.existencias
    WHERE productoID = envaseID_in AND bodegaID = bod_origenID_in AND status IN (1,2)
    ORDER BY fecInsert ASC; -- Asumiendo que 'fecInsert' indica la antigüedad del lote

   -- Manejadores de Salida
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
    BEGIN
        CLOSE cur_lotes_envasado;
        CLOSE cur_envases;
    END;
    
    -- PASO 1: Verificar existencia total de lotes seleccionados y obtener precio por kg
    SELECT ifnull(sum(stock),0), AVG(precio)
    INTO total_kg_envasar, precio_por_kg
    FROM controlstock.lotesenvasado 
    WHERE ordenID = OrdenID_in;

    -- Validar total KG para envasar
    IF total_kg_envasar < cantidad_kg_envasar THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No hay suficientes KG. para envasar';
    END IF;

    -- PASO 2: Verificar Existencia de Envases y sacar precio unitario
    SELECT ifnull(sum(cantidad),0) 
    INTO total_envases
    FROM controlstock.productobodega 
    WHERE productoID = envaseID_in AND bodegaID = bod_origenID_in;
    
    set precio_envase = (SELECT AVG(precio) FROM controlstock.existencias WHERE productoID = envaseID_in AND bodegaID = bod_origenID_in AND status IN (1,2));

    -- Validar total envases para envasar
    IF total_envases < cantidad_envase THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No hay suficientes envases para envasar';
    END IF;

    -- Setear Kg Restantes
    SET kg_restante = cantidad_kg_envasar;
    
    -- Setear Envases Restantes
    SET envases_restantes = cantidad_envase;

    -- PASO 3: Descontar del producto granel y de los envases
    OPEN cur_lotes_envasado;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur_lotes_envasado INTO lote_id, lote_precio, lote_cantidad;

        -- Terminar Bucle cuando no quedan KG
        IF kg_restante <= 0 THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        IF lote_cantidad <= kg_restante THEN
            UPDATE controlstock.lotesenvasado
            SET stock = 0
            WHERE id = lote_id;
            SET kg_restante = kg_restante - lote_cantidad;
        ELSE
            UPDATE controlstock.lotesenvasado
            SET stock = lote_cantidad - kg_restante
            WHERE id = lote_id;
            SET kg_restante = 0;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;


    CLOSE cur_lotes_envasado;

    OPEN cur_envases;

    envase_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur_envases INTO envase_lote_id, envase_cantidad;

        IF envases_restantes <= 0 THEN
            LEAVE envase_loop;
        END IF;

        IF envase_cantidad <= envases_restantes THEN
            UPDATE controlstock.existencias
            SET stock = 0
            WHERE id = envase_lote_id;
            SET envases_restantes = envases_restantes - envase_cantidad;
        ELSE
            UPDATE controlstock.existencias
            SET stock = envase_cantidad - envases_restantes AND status = 2
            WHERE id = envase_lote_id;
            SET envases_restantes = 0;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur_envases;

    -- PASO 4: Calcular el precio unitario del producto envasado
    SET precio_unitario = precio_por_kg * capacidad_envase + precio_envase;

    -- PASO 5: Añadir el producto envasado al inventario
    INSERT INTO controlstock.itemsenvasado (documentoID, productoID, bodegaID, lote, unidadID, precio, cantidad, stock, userID, status)
    VALUES (ordenID_in, productoID_in, bod_destinoID_in, lote_orden_in, 4, precio_unitario, cantidad_envase, cantidad_envase, userID_in, 1);


END

When I run it, it executes only the first cursor and then I get the error

ER_SP_CURSOR_NOT_OPEN: Cursor is not open

I have tried to move the cursors, but in MySQL Workbench I get the errors

DECLARE is not valid at this position, expecting END


My guess is the NOT FOUND handler is running, so the cursors are being closed.

ER_SP_CURSOR_NOT_OPEN: Cursor is not open This error is generated in the handler for CLOSE cur_envases; statement.

When NOT FOUND is obtained over 1st cursor then EXIT handler is fired. After its statements (closing cursors) are executed then the flow EXITs (leaves) your stored procedure.
You must use CONTINUE handler which sets a variable but returns the process flow to the firing point, check the variable immediately after FETCH and leave the cycle if the variable is set.
Schematically:
CREATE PROCEDURE ..
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE CURSOR cursor1 ...
DECLARE CURSOR cursor2 ...
DECLARE CONTINUE /* execute then return back */ HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
BEGIN 
    SET done = TRUE; 
END;

BEGIN
    ...
    OPEN cursor1;
    label1: LOOP
        FETCH cursor1 INTO ...      -- jump to continue handler when cursor is empty
        IF done THEN                -- check does 1st cursor is empty
            LEAVE label1;           -- if true then leave cycle but continue execution   
        END IF;                         
        ...
    END LOOP label1;
    CLOSE cursor1;
    SET done = FALSE;            -- reset variable value for 2nd cursor checking
    ...
    OPEN cursor2;
    label2: LOOP
        FETCH cursor2 INTO ...
        IF done THEN LEAVE label2; END IF;
    ...
    END LOOP label2;
    CLOSE cursor2;
    ... 

